# Laravel/PHP: New Instance of Model Class within Method of This Model

Tags: php, function, class, oop, laravel-4

New to Laravel and still fresh to OOP! I'm assuming this has more to do with OOP than strictly Laravel.

So my main problem is that I am trying to pass all rows from a database table called 'fin_income_category' via a method in my model called Income to a controller called PlannerController. To do this I have created a static method within Income called getIncomeCategories()

First of all, here is my __construct method within Income:

```
public function __construct($income, array $attributes = array()){
  parent::__construct($attributes);

  $this->table = $income; 
}
```

And here is the getIncomeCategories method also within Income:

```
public static function getIncomeCategories(){
   $category = new self('fin_income_category');
   $categories = $category->all();
   return $categories;
}
```

Finally, here is the edit($id) method within the PlannerController where I am to call this method and pass the categories along to my view. Note that only the first statement in this function is the one in question...the others work fine:

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $income_categories = Income::getIncomeCategories();

   $newIncome = new Income('fin_income');
   $newRecord = $newIncome->where('id', '=', $id)->get();

   return View::make('planner.edit', array('record'=>$newRecord, 'categories'=>$income_categories));
}
```

When I run the code like this I receive an error from Laravel:

> ErrorException
>
> Missing argument 1 for Income::__construct(),
> called in /opt/lampstack/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 615 and defined

In other cases where I have instantiated a new Income I have not received this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the getIncomeCategories() to this

```
    public static function getIncomeCategories(){
           $category = new self('fin_income_category');
           return $category->get()->toArray();
   }
```

The reason why your code didn't work is because the eloquent `all()` found in

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; the code snippet is found below

public static function all($columns = array('*'))
{
    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->get($columns);
}
```

is instantiating a static class which is bound to the called class which is your `Income` Model Class in your case, and in the process requesting the arguments in the constructor